# String to int conversion not working swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to do some operation on an array of digits. i wish to combine them and do something. i know reduce operation also works but i am not sure why this is not working.

```
var digits = [7,2,8,5,0,9,1,2,9,5,3,6,6,7,3,2,8,4,3,7]
var strDigits = ""
for i in digits
{
    strDigits += String(i)
}
print(strDigits)
if let number = Int(strDigits) {
    print(number)
}
else{
    print("didnt work")
}
```

this will print didnt work. if i reduce the elements in array by 1 it starts working again and print the number. why is the limitation that string cant be cast to int if the string is too long?

Comment: "72850912953667328437“ is too large for a (64-bit) integer ...

Comment: yeah that was so silly of me. thanks

Comment: Use UInt64. Its range is 0 to 18446744073709551615.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concat all the numbers to string, the number then becomes too big for `Int64` too handle, whose upper limit is 9223372036854775807, whereas your number is 72850912953667328447. 
Edited for Martin's correction.

Comment: `Int64.max`  is 2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807, not 2147483647